# I'm a beginner, I can't understand the following errors in my c++ program

Tags: c++

```
//This program averages 4 grades and assigns a letter grade based on the numeric average.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int g1, g2, g3, g4; //Numeric grades to be averaged.

    cout << "This program averages 4 grades. \n"; // Gathers number inputs to output GPA (Grade Point Average)
    cout << "Enter first grade \n";
    cin >> g1;
    cout << "Enter second grade \n";
    cin >> g2;
    cout << "Enter third grade \n";
    cin >> g3;
    cout << "Enter fourth grade \n";
    cin >> g4;
    cout << "Your average is: \n";

    const int 
        gpa = ((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4.0); // Average of g1, g2, g3, and g4.
        rep = "Your GPA letter grade is: \n"; // Placeholder for the letter grade reply string.

    cout << gpa

    cout << gpa; // Outputs letter grade string
    if (gpa >= 90)
        cout << rep "A";
    else if (gpa >= 80)
        cout << rep "B";
    else if (gpa >= 70)
        cout << rep "C";
    else if (gpa >= 60)
        cout << rep "D";
    else if (gpa >= 0)
        cout << rep "F";
    else 
        cout  << "Invalid grade entered, enter positive digits only. \n"

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I receive these error messages:

```
1>c:\users\seven\source\repos\project2\project2\source.cpp(9): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'

1>c:\users\seven\source\repos\project2\project2\source.cpp(9): error C2270: 'main': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions

1>c:\users\seven\source\repos\project2\project2\source.cpp(14): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
```

I especially don't understand the first error. Why would I ever want a ; to precede int? ";int", and in every case there is an ; preceding "int" on the line before. Sorry if I'm not asking for help properly. Doing my best, thanks!

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/BKZILI35460) the mentioned errors. Are you sure, that this is the code, that you are compiling? There are plenty of other errors, which are pretty clear in my opinion, though.

Comment: The error messages do not appear to match the source you posted. It looks like you posted a different version of the source than was used to produce those error messages. You should fix that before any questions can be answered. (Did you change the source file in an editor and not save it before compiling? That is one reason the source you see could differ from the source being compiled.)

Comment: Note you're missing a semi-colon on `cout << gpa`, but that wouldn't cause those errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int g1, g2, g3, g4; //Numeric grades to be averaged.

cout << "This program averages 4 grades. \n"; // Gathers number inputs to output GPA (Grade Point Average)
cout << "Enter first grade \n";
cin >> g1;
cout << "Enter second grade \n";
cin >> g2;
cout << "Enter third grade \n";
cin >> g3;
cout << "Enter fourth grade \n";
cin >> g4;
cout << "Your average is: \n";

const int gpa = ((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4.0); // Average of g1, g2, g3, and g4.
const string rep = "Your GPA letter grade is: \n"; // Placeholder for the letter grade reply string.

cout << gpa;

cout << gpa; // Outputs letter grade string
if (gpa >= 90) {
    cout << rep << "A";
}else if (gpa >= 80){
    cout << rep << "B";
}else if (gpa >= 70){
    cout << rep << "C";
}else if (gpa >= 60){
    cout << rep << "D";
}else if (gpa >= 0){
    cout << rep << "F";
}else{ 
    cout  << "Invalid grade entered, enter positive digits only. \n";
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Please check your syntax. All errors were caused by the syntax error.

Comment: you shouldn't concatenate in `cout << rep + "A";` you should use `<<` instead.